# how to change class of service for an extention in panasonic pbx using tapi

Tags: windows, telephony, tapi, pbx

I made a simple telephony application in which i am retrieving all the extension lines of the PBX .Now as per my need i have to select the particular extension line and change the class of service (COS) of that line .I am using TAPI3Lib .dll and Panasonic TSP.Any help will be appreciated ..

Thanks in Advance